# Spring web flow can't resolve service bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have got following problem.
I defined following service class

```
package godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.service.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.domain.Cart;
import godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.domain.repository.CartRepository;
import godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.exception.InvalidCartException;
import godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.service.CartService;

@Service
public class CartServiceImpl implements CartService {
    @Autowired
    CartRepository cartRepository;

    public Cart create(Cart cart) {
        return cartRepository.create(cart);
    }

    public Cart read(String cartId) {
        return cartRepository.read(cartId);
    }

    public void update(String cartId, Cart cart) {
        cartRepository.update(cartId, cart);
    }

    public void delete(String cartId) {
        cartRepository.delete(cartId);
    }

    public Cart validate(String cartId) {
        Cart cart = cartRepository.read(cartId);
        if(cart==null || cart.getCartItems().size()==0) {
        throw new InvalidCartException(cartId);
        }
        return cart;
    }
}
```

Class is getting loaded by spring ( It's found by component scan and I can use it in other classes by autowiring)
And I need to use this bean in spring web flow. My flow looks like this:

```
<var name="order" class="godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.domain.Order" />


<action-state id="addCartToOrder">
    <evaluate expression="cartServiceImpl.validate(requestScope.cartId)"
        result="order.cart" />
    <transition to="InvalidCartWarning"
        on-exception="godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.exception.InvalidCartException"/>
    <transition to="loadCustomerAddress" />
</action-state>
```

Everything should work, but somehow expression parser can't resolve my service bean. The error I'm getting:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/ElectronicsStore] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@3d6c7f1e targetAction = [EvaluateAction@43e3c391 expression = cartServiceImpl.validate(requestScope.cartId), resultExpression = order.cart], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'addCartToOrder' of flow 'checkout' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'cartServiceImpl' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:51)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:87)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.start(Flow.java:527)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:368)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.start(FlowExecutionImpl.java:223)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.launchExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:140)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Full webflow config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

    <var name="order" class="godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.domain.Order" />


    <action-state id="addCartToOrder">
        <evaluate expression="cartServiceImpl.validate(requestScope.cartId)"
            result="order.cart" />
        <transition to="InvalidCartWarning"
            on-exception="godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.exception.InvalidCartException" />
        <transition to="loadCustomerAddress" />
    </action-state>

        <action-state id="loadCustomerAddress">
        <evaluate expression="customerServiceImpl.getCustomerByEmail(currentUser.name)"
            result="order.customer" />
            <transition to="customer"
            on-exception="org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException"/>
            <transition to="customer" />
        </action-state>


    <subflow-state id="customer" subflow="checkout/customer">
      <input name="order" value="order"/>
      <transition on="customerReady" to="orderConfirmation" />
    </subflow-state>


    <view-state id="orderConfirmation">
        <transition on="orderConfirmed" to="processOrder" />
        <transition on="backToCustomerInfo" to="customer" />
    </view-state>

    <action-state id="processOrder">
        <evaluate expression="orderServiceImpl.saveOrder(order)" />
        <transition to="thankCustomer" />
    </action-state>

    <view-state id="InvalidCartWarning">
        <transition to="endState"/>
    </view-state>

    <view-state id="thankCustomer" model="order">
        <transition to="endState"/>
    </view-state>

    <end-state id="endState"/>  

    <end-state id="cancelCheckout" view = "checkOutCancelled.jsp"/>     

    <global-transitions>
        <transition on = "cancel" to="cancelCheckout" />
    </global-transitions>

</flow>
```

flow configuration:

```
package godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.webflow.config.AbstractFlowConfiguration;
import org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.FlowDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.support.FlowBuilderServices;
import org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutor;
import org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping;


public class FlowConfiguration extends AbstractFlowConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    Validator validator;
    @Bean
    public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
        return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder()
            .setBasePath("/WEB-INF/flows")
            .setFlowBuilderServices(flowBuilderServices())
            .addFlowLocationPattern("/**/*-flow.xml")
            .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
        return getFlowExecutorBuilder(flowRegistry()).build();
    }
    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping()
    {
        FlowHandlerMapping fh = new FlowHandlerMapping();
        fh.setFlowRegistry(flowRegistry());
        return fh;
    }
    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter()
    {
        FlowHandlerAdapter fh = new FlowHandlerAdapter();
        fh.setFlowExecutor(flowExecutor());
        return fh;
    }
    @Bean
    public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices()
    {
        return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder()
                .setValidator(validator)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Also, rest of classes:

```
package godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.config;

import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration;
import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration.Dynamic;

import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;



public class ElectronicsStoreWebInitialiser extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic encodingFilter = servletContext
                .addFilter("encoding-filter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        encodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        encodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        encodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(Dynamic registration) {
        registration.setMultipartConfig(
                new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp/images",
                        2097152, 4194304, 0));
    }
}
```

and class that imports flow config:

```
package godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.config;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.View;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.PathMatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView;
import org.springframework.web.util.UrlPathHelper;
import godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.domain.Product;

@Configuration
@Import(godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.config.FlowConfiguration.class)
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "godziszewski.patryk")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true); 
    return resolver;
    }

     @Override
        public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {

            UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
            urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);

            configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
        }


    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return validator();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resource/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
    @Bean
    TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tiles = new TilesConfigurer();
        tiles.setDefinitions(new String[] {
                "/WEB-INF/tiles/definition/tile-definition.xml"
        });
        tiles.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return tiles;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
        TilesViewResolver tv = new TilesViewResolver();
        tv.setOrder(-2);
        return  tv;
    }
    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource rb = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        rb.setBasename("messages");
        return rb;
    }
    @Bean
    public StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }
    @Bean
    public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentResolver() {
        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver cn = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();

        List<View> listOfViews = new ArrayList<View>();
        listOfViews.add(jsonView());
        listOfViews.add(xmlView());

        cn.setDefaultViews(listOfViews);

        return cn;
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2JsonView jsonView() {
        MappingJackson2JsonView mj= new MappingJackson2JsonView();
        mj.setPrettyPrint(true);
        return mj;
    }



    @Bean
    public MarshallingView xmlView() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller ja = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        ja.setClassesToBeBound(Product.class);

        MarshallingView mv = new MarshallingView(ja);

        return mv;
    }
    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean lv = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        lv.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return lv;
    }
}
```

Changed file

```
package godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.config;





import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.binding.convert.service.DefaultConversionService;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.webflow.config.AbstractFlowConfiguration;
import org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.FlowDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.support.FlowBuilderServices;
import org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutor;
import org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter;
import org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping;


public class FlowConfiguration extends AbstractFlowConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    Validator validator;
    @Bean
    public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
        return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder(flowBuilderServices())
                //flow registry makes flow not recognize beans ?
            //.setFlowBuilderServices(flowBuilderServices())
            .setBasePath("/WEB-INF/flows")
            .addFlowLocationPattern("/**/*-flow.xml")
            .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
        return getFlowExecutorBuilder(flowRegistry()).build();
    }
    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping()
    {
        FlowHandlerMapping fh = new FlowHandlerMapping();
        fh.setFlowRegistry(flowRegistry());
        return fh;
    }
    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter()
    {
        FlowHandlerAdapter fh = new FlowHandlerAdapter();
        fh.setFlowExecutor(flowExecutor());
        return fh;
    }
    @Bean
    public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices()
    {
        return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder()
                .setValidator(validator)
                .setDevelopmentMode(true)
                .setConversionService(conversionService())
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public DefaultConversionService conversionService()
    {
        return new DefaultConversionService();
    }
}
```

I'm adding github link to my repository, maybe you can find something wrong in there (about the flow)
https://github.com/pgod/ElectronicsStore

Comment: Try @Service("cartServiceImpl") on the CartServiceImpl class, or change the webflow reference to cartService

Comment: I tried first one, with no luck. I don't understand the other tip, I don't create reference anywhere, I just need to access already created bean. I update the post with full webflow config

Comment: could you add your actual webflow config where you set flow builder etc.?

Comment: also your regular spring config, and the order in which you load them, for instance my configuration has a web-config, which import a dispatcher-servlet-config which imports my webflow-config in that order.

Comment: did you try with any other beans? like session scoped or anything else? validators, anything?

Comment: I really don't know much about the java configuration, I still use xml. Don't you need @Configuration on your FlowConfiguration class as well?

Comment: per documentation `<p>Provides functionality equivalent to the {@code <import/>} element in Spring XML.
 * Allows for importing {@code @Configuration} classes...`

Comment: I needed to remove that annotation because beans were loaded in wrong order.The bean that does problems for me is flowBuilderServices, when I remove it from config webflow resolves bean, but I can't use validation then.

Comment: that's strange, spring should be able to figure out the order on its own.

Comment: try adding conversionService. look [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=96EvCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA269&lpg=PA269&dq=getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder()&source=bl&ots=0kJrrygupb&sig=B8_TZoDuN1TXvEV_AenU2VDNRII&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_rv2So-fOAhULmR4KHcIuB4oQ6AEIPTAG#v=onepage&q=getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder()&f=false)

Comment: flowBuilderServices messes up my flow, if I don't set it in flow registry, beans are recognized as they should :/ 
I don't know how to properly set it, I've tried like everything that came to my mind

Comment: Maybe you can try: 1. use CartService instead of CartServiceImpl  2. change the scope to flow

Comment: Flow can't seem to resolve any beans - even those from configuration files  that are loaded at the start of application.I tried using interface, but i'm getting same error :/ it's really strange. What do you mean by changing scope to flow?