# Spring webflow - I have to set application context manually

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I'm having a weird problem with my Spring application with Spring Webflow. The problem is, when I set flow like in documentation:

```
@Bean
public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices()
{
    return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder()
            .setValidator(validator)
            .build();
}
```

It does not find beans in my application.I described this problem here:
[Spring web flow can't resolve service bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171554/spring-web-flow-cant-resolve-service-bean)
However when I set application context manually like this :

```
@Bean
public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices()
{
    FlowBuilderServices fbs = getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder().build();
    fbs.setApplicationContext(getApplicationContext());
    fbs.setValidator(validator);
    return fbs;
}
```

It works fine. I haven't seen yet someone setting application config manually like I do, so i think there is some problem with config of my application.
Here is my application config:

```
public class ElectronicsStoreWebInitialiser extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(Dynamic registration) {
        registration.setMultipartConfig(
                new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp/images",
                        2097152, 4194304, 0));
    }
}
```

Webconfig:

```
@Configuration
@Import(godziszewski.patryk.ElectronicsStore.config.FlowConfiguration.class)
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "godziszewski.patryk")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true); 
        return resolver;
    }
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
         UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
         urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
         configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
     }
    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return validator();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resource/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
    @Bean
    TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tiles = new TilesConfigurer();
        tiles.setDefinitions(new String[] {
                "/WEB-INF/tiles/definition/tile-definition.xml"
        });
        tiles.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return tiles;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
        TilesViewResolver tv = new TilesViewResolver();
        tv.setOrder(-2);
        return  tv;
    }
    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource rb = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        rb.setBasename("messages");
        return rb;
    }
    @Bean
    public StandardServletMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }
    @Bean
    public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentResolver() {
        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver cn = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();

        List<View> listOfViews = new ArrayList<View>();
        listOfViews.add(jsonView());
        listOfViews.add(xmlView());

        cn.setDefaultViews(listOfViews);

        return cn;
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2JsonView jsonView() {
        MappingJackson2JsonView mj= new MappingJackson2JsonView();
        mj.setPrettyPrint(true);
        return mj;
    }



    @Bean
    public MarshallingView xmlView() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller ja = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        ja.setClassesToBeBound(Product.class);
        MarshallingView mv = new MarshallingView(ja);
        return mv;
    }
    @Bean
    public Validator validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean lv = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        lv.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return lv;
    }
}
```

And flow configuration:

```
public class FlowConfiguration extends AbstractFlowConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    Validator validator;
    @Bean
    public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
        return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder()
            .setFlowBuilderServices(flowBuilderServices())
            .setBasePath("/WEB-INF/flows")
            .addFlowLocationPattern("/**/*-flow.xml")
            .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
        return getFlowExecutorBuilder(flowRegistry())
                    .addFlowExecutionListener(securityFlowExecutionListener())
                    .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping()
    {
        FlowHandlerMapping fh = new FlowHandlerMapping();
        fh.setFlowRegistry(flowRegistry());
        return fh;
    }
    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter()
    {
        FlowHandlerAdapter fh = new FlowHandlerAdapter();
        fh.setFlowExecutor(flowExecutor());
        return fh;
    }
    @Bean
    public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices()
    {
        return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder()
                .setValidator(validator)
                .build();
        /*FlowBuilderServices fbs = getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder().build();
        System.out.println(fbs.getApplicationContext());
        fbs.setApplicationContext(getApplicationContext());
        fbs.setValidator(validator);
        return fbs;*/

    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFlowExecutionListener securityFlowExecutionListener()
    {
        return new SecurityFlowExecutionListener();
    }
}
```

Now it doesn't bother me that much, cause when I set application context manually - it works like it should, but it's rather weird behaviour and I spent some time figuring out the fix and I feel that it should not work like this. Can you take a look at my code? Thanks in advance